# Linux server configuration rereading using signals

Tags: c, linux, signals, config

I am making a server in C that is supposed to run as daemon on a Linux operating system. I also have a logging system and I will do some UART reading. I read somewhere that, while running a daemon, SIGHUP can be used to initiate rereading the config file and updating some values. My question is how should this be done without potential danger of changing the values in the middle of an operation that should have them the same in the end as they were in the beginning (for instance, if I'm reading from a serial port, I don't want my BAUD to change in the middle of receiving a package).
Locks came to mind but I don't really want to change the program so that it checks for some indicator if it should change the values before/after entering a function.

EDIT:
If there is a way to make functions atomic in the sense of signal handling (signal handlers will wait for those functions to finish before proceeding), that would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a global*  boolean variable that is set inside signal handler upon receiving a signal.

Then, you determine the point in your main loop where it is safe to re-read the config file and reinitialize whatever you need. In that point you analyse the value of said boolean variable (and any other possible blocking conditions) and take an action. Don't forget to clear that flag variable so you don't reinitialize everything again on the next iteration.

---

* global here is visible to both signal handler and main loop

Comment: That's what I had in mind when I stated "Locks came to mind but I don't really want to change the program so that it checks for some indicator if it should change the values before/after entering a function." Maybe I used the wrong expression "locks". The fixed point is a better option so one iteration is atomic in the abovementioned sense. That is the way to do it as far as I know but I was looking for something different, if there is something different.

Comment: What for are you looking then? For a universal method that would be capable to determine if it is safe to apply a changes from within a signal handler? I doubt such method exist.

Comment: I was thinking there might be something more to C, a principle used in these situations. The more I think about it, the more it seems illogical. Thanks for the good answer.